# How to marshal an object into XML-RPC format in Java?

Tags: java, parsing, serialization, xml-rpc

I am developing a web application where I have requirement to marshal an object into XML-RPC format. What marshaling method should I use?

Let's suppose I have below POJO class.

```
public class Employee
{
    private Integer empId;
    private String empName;
}
```

Expected result(XML-RPC) of its object should looks like below.

```
<methodCall>
    <methodName>getEmployee</methodName>
    <params>
        <param>
            <struct>
                <member>
                    <name>empId</name>
                    <value>
                        <int>23</int>
                    </value>
                </member>
                <member>
                    <name>empName</name>
                    <value>
                        <string>John</string>
                    </value>
                </member>
            </struct>
        </param>
    </params>
</methodCall>
```

Comment: Are you sure you really want to represent a pojo as a `methodCall` with parameters?

Comment: I have corrected xml-rpc representation of object. Check now please.

Answer (score 1):

Parsing is something you'd do if you had the XML and wanted to instantiate the object from it.  In that case you'd parse the XML using a DOM parser and walk the tree to create the object.

One good way to create an XML snippet from an object is to use a template solution, like Velocity or Freemarker.  You pass the template and an object instance to the template engine, which creates an XML as String for you.

This problem is even easier if you prefer JSON to XML.  You can use Jackson JSON to go back and forth between objects and JSON.  Your JSON messages will be lighter than XML.

Comment: Yes, JSON is preferable. But requirement is to use XML-RPC only.

Comment: Template it is, then.  Velocity has been updated recently, but it was removed from Spring Boot as a web MVC choice.  Try FreeMarker.